# Does pseudoterminal transfer byte stream or message?

Tags: linux, ipc, pseudoterminal

From The Linux Programming Interface

[image]

under "data transfer" under "communication", we have "byte stream", "message" and "pseudoterminal".

Does pseudoterminal belong to byte stream instead, just like how pipe belongs?

If not, why?

Comment: It's neither. That's why under data transfer you have *three* branches and not two. A pseudoterminal is a pseudoterminal; it behaves very much like an old-school hardware terminal, and as a consequence the master side and the slave side must cooperate so that they both have the same understanding of the current mode (cooked, rare, raw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the various modes a pseudoterminal can be in: in raw mode, it would behave much like a byte stream, but in cooked mode, it becomes  more message-like.